# Prefer throw or reject when failing promise asynchronously

Tags: javascript, error-handling, promise, ecmascript-6, bluebird

I have a Bluebird promise that wraps an AJAX request and need to reject the promise when the request fails. I would like to provide the reason why the request failed, largely drawn from the status code, to any catch blocks that may be attached. To achieve that, I have `UnauthorizedError` and `NotFoundError` and similar classes, all extending `Error` to work with Bluebird's pattern-matching `catch`.

The part I'm not sure on is whether I should `throw` or call the reject handler. My code looks something like:

```
class Request {
  // other methods

  send(method, url, args, body) {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
      let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open(method, url);

      xhr.onload = () => {
        res(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
      };

      xhr.onerror = () => {
        let status = xhr.status;
        switch (status) {
          case 401:
            // Should I use throw:
            throw new UnauthorizedError(url);
            // or
            rej(new UnauthorizedError(url));
        }
      };

      xhr.send();
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Inside the `Promise` constructor

The promise constructor is throw safe, but by nature you're typically not dealing with throw safe things inside - so for example the following is not safe:

```
new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
     setTimeout(function(){
         // NEVER throw here, it'll throw globally and not reject the promise
     }, 100);
});
```

The promise constructor is typically only used to convert callback APIs to promises and since callbacks are not throw-safe like promises you have to reject when they error asynchronously (rather than throw).

#### Inside a `then` handler

The two are identical functionally. When you `throw` from a `then` handler you're returning a rejected promise.  I prefer to throw because it is more explicit that an error happened than a `return` but it does not matter.

This is true for any promise implementation except Angular 1.x's `$q` which distinguishes the two - but it's the odd ball out (when you `throw` there it logs even if you handle the error).

#### In your code

In your code there are several bugs in the way you reject and handle the promises. Promises are very robust in that they handle errors gracefully for you - you have to be extremely careful when you convert callback APIs to promises in that regard:

```
class Request {
    // other methods

    send(method, url, args, body) {
        return new Promise((res, rej) => {  // it's good that new Promise is the first
            let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); // line since it's throw-safe. This is why it
            xhr.open(method, url);          // was chosen for the API and not deferreds

            xhr.onload = () => {
                // This _needs_ a try/catch, it will fail if responseText
                // is invalid JSON and will throw to the global scope instead of rejecting
                res(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
            };

            xhr.onerror = () => {
                let status = xhr.status;
                switch (status) {
                case 401:
                    // this _must_ be a reject, it should also generally be surrounded
                    // with a try/catch
                    rej(new UnauthorizedError(url));
                }
            };

            xhr.send(); // it's important that this is in the promise constructor
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What should be in the try/catch for `JSON.parse`? `reject(new ParseError());`?

Comment: @FlorianMargaine even just a `try{ res(JSON.parse(...)); } catch(e){ rej(e); }` is fine - as long as it's a promise rejection and not a "wild" error.

Comment: Why do we need to surround the rejection handler with `try..catch`?

Comment: Well, `xhr.onerror` might execute asynchronously - at which point it's not executing inside the promise constructor so a thrown exception could not possibly be caught by it. This is exactly like the `setTimeout` example - you can't catch errors in async functions you don't control. You must manually convert exceptions to rejections which is normally what the promise library does for you.

Comment: Another option would be to have onload resolve and onerror reject immediately, and then use a `.then(xhr => JSON.parse(xhr.responseText), err => { if (status === 401) throw new UnauthorusedError(url);  })`. Then you don't have to worry about doing your own try/catch. Just make sure the only action you do in async callbacks is calling `resolve` or `reject`.